# Не работают Z-index'ы

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Уже горит этой шляпы, код скинуть не смогу - получится слишком много. На скрине все отобразил, иконки (z-index:-1)с помощью паралакса имеют меньшую скорость и должны как бы выплывать из под верхнего блока(z-index:10), НО ЗИНДЕКСЫ НЕ РАБОТАЮТ.Пробовал назначать Position:relative, ничего не помогает. В чем может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не могу привести минимальный пример, потому что он будет работать:) Вставлять сюда код целого проекта не считаю разумным, поэтому если можете дать совет только на словах, то дайте. Буду благодарен и этому

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю что ты используешь для блока social, но можно использовать два свойства, это `fixed` (он позиционируется относительно `body`, даже если есть сверху `relative` или `absolute`) и свойство `sticky`, оно позиционируется относительно первого `relative` или `absolute`. Можешь с этим поиграться.

Ещё что пришло на ум: если у тебя один родитель и ты верхнему родителю задаёшь `z-index: 10`, а ребёнку `z-index: -1`, то по сути так `z-index` не работает. Ребёнок не может стать ниже чем родитель. Ты не можешь засунуть ребёнка под родителя (если это не псевдоэлементы after, before).

Лучший способ, чтобы у тебя было два разных родителя и потом у `header` `position: relative` и `z-index: 10`, а у блока social  `position: sticky` и `z-index: 1`.

В общем это мои предположения, пробуй, удачи.